# How to tell if there exists a vector orthogonal to half your vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

Given a set of $N$ vectors each with $n$ entries from the integers. How can you determine efficiently if there is any non-zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is orthogonal to half of them?

Comment: You probably mean non-zero vector as Timbuc has efficiently answered your question as it stands. If you do mean non-zero, my guess is that if you have less than $2n$ vectors in your set, it always exists. Im trying to formalize the proof for this.

Comment: "No non-zero vector is orthogonal to half of them" is equivalent to "any half of them spans the whole space". If you put them in a matrix and denote it as $M$, it is equivalent to "each submatrix of $M$ of order $n \times \lceil N/2 \rceil$ has a full rank".

Answer (score 1):

There always is: take any half of those vectors $\;\{v_1,...,v_m\}\;$ and put $\;W=Span\{v_1,..,v_m\}\;$. Then any vector in $\;W^\perp\;$ is perpendicular to $\;W\;$ and thus to each vector $\;v_1,...,v_m\;$ .

Even if $\;W=\Bbb R^n\;$ then $\;W^\perp=\{0\}\;$ , so there's always a vector perpendicular to any set of vectors.

Comment: I meant non-zero.  The number of vectors could be really large compared to $n$ so I don't think you can just pick any half can you?

Comment: Indeed @felix. As user30535 commented if you happen to have $\;2n\;$ or more vectors and you choose half of them  being a spanning set of $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ then there won't be a non-zero vector perpendicular to them all.

Comment: Is my question equivalent to determining the rank of all submatrices of size $N/2$ or something similar do you think?